# Changing the <p> class depending on the content, which is added by clicking in different table cells

Tags: jquery, css, list, html-table

I'm working on a periodic table of elements made with a html table, and I need to make a different chemical compound buttons where the user needs to click the specific elements that make those compounds, which then will change the button color.

I already got the button set working, along with the specific letters for each element being added onto a paragraph, so if I click three times on the table on H, I'll add three H's on the paragraph.

The thing is, I know barely nothing on Jquery, I just started learning Javascript (conditions, arrays, etc) and I'm working just recycling code people help me with or that I find on the internet.

Right now, I arrived at a condition I can't seem to get working, that is to recognize that I inserted HHO and change the button class (the button is actually a list aligned horizonally).

I'm trying something along the lines of

```
if($(".respostas").html().contains("H")){
    $("#btn1").removeClass("liPress");
    $("#btn1").addClass("liRight");
}
```

(on the example, I'm trying with just H, for simplicity)

Does anyone can help me with this? 
It is the first time I ask a question and if I did something wrong, please tell me and I'll correct it. 
Thanks

ps. I'm including the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abcdario/Jr5nM/4/
On the link, it is only possible for me to start picking elements (the K and H) as I click the hidrogen peroxide button, That's planned, but I can't seem to find a way to compare what gets added to the paragraph for, once I add the right letters, it change the class of the button selected for liRight.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your page? Would be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: I just added it, thanks for taking the time =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
.indexOf("H")
```

instead of

```
.contains("H")
```

As contains checks if there are objects inside, however, I believe you are looking for string inside object (in html code).

Anyway, here is a demo expaining how to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/NA8jz/

Click link with "H" and the button's background color will change. A link without "H" won't execute the code inside "IF".

Comment: After checking your demo, I noticed that I'd need a button to confirm-check if the letters were there and change the class with this condition. After creating the button, it worked. Thank you, man. =D